# Add extra column to 2D array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
char[,] DataFile=new char[310,6720]
```

Now I want to increase the number of columns in DataFile array dynamically, so after increase number of columns it will look like:

```
char[,] DataFile=new char[310,6726]
```

Is it possible, and if yes then how? I read about the `IsFixedSize` property but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: That code is invalid. Furthermore, you really should think about using a `List<T>` or something if you want dynamic sizing

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new` you are allocating a new memory object, you're not resizing an existing one.

In the case of arrays you can create a `new` object and then copy the values to it, albeit, this is terrible for memory and performance. I'd advice you refactor code to use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The previous poster already mentioned using  List, but you may even go further and try to redesign. The Name "DataFile" suggests that you are trying to serialize some data that is in memory. It seems to be a bad idea to bring the data into another format in memory just to write it down to disk then. Could you tell us more about your aim? What do those cells of Char represent?

Answer (score 0):

You could interchange the rows and columns, so your array is now char[6720,310]. Then, instead of adding some more columns, just add some more rows.